# Should perfectly fine questions that have been closed and have an answer be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open, context

I just came across a question that had been closed by votes. The question itself seems perfectly fine to me, and I don't see any reason to close it.

The question also received an excellent answer, and there is not much to be gained by additional answers. So I don't see any "profit" by voting to re-open the question, even though I don't think the question should have been closed.

In such a situation should a vote to re-open the question be started?

(The specific question this is about [$C^*$-algebras generated by one element](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3441859).)

Comment: I'm somewhat worried about math.stackexchange being flooded by poor quality questions about trigonometry, analytic geometry, and calculus. I'm considerably less worried about being overrun by questions about C*-algebras.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well then don't miss that one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445053/a-description-of-compact-projection

Answer (score 6):

There are two commonly observed ways to deal with "PSQs", Problem Statement Questions, that is homework-looking questions where no context or personal thoughts are provided:

- one of them is to answer them (either because you're rep farming, or for whatever reason you feel like answering)
- the other is to close them for lack of content and/or downvote.

This will most likely explain why the question you point at was closed. I'm not saying that this particular question is necessarily HW, but it does lack context.

Now despite the fact that a question has a good answer, it is always possible that another answer with another point of view could be given, so if you believe that a question did not deserve to be closed, then you should vote for it to be reopened (if you are ready to spend time voting, that is).

Comment: For the record, I have always assumed that PSQ stood for Problem **Statement** Question:  such a question is simply a statement of a problem, such as what you might find in a textbook.  I think that *every* question on the site is some kind of Problem **Solving** Question, in that the asker has a problem and they want to find a solution. ;)

Comment: @XanderHenderson You're right, it makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: It could also be Piece of S*** Questions, or Particularly Stupid Questions, Partially Stated Questions,  Please Solve Questions, etc.